# How to stop upload in background?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on a button how do I stop an upload because it is still uploading in the background?:

Below is code:

```
    $(".imageCancel").click(function() {
          $(".upload_target").attr("src","#"); //iframe
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up your question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153916/how-to-cancel-a-file-upload-by-clicking-on-a-cancel-button

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207501/stopping-a-iframe-from-loading-a-page-using-javascript

Comment: @joeframbach not sure if you are being sarcastic, but doing that is not encouraged, he should have edited the question instead of reposting a new one

Answer (score 0):

Take a look this maybe helps to u : [Jquery File Start-Cancel Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove and then recreate input file upload element of document. 
it is not perfect, but it'll work.